# What does "would yet" means in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> However, Holo, who **would yet live** for hundreds of years...

As the title suggests, what does *would yet* mean in the sentence above? I take the whole sentence as "Holo who lived for hundreds of years," but I fail to see what is the function of *would yet* in the sentence nor what it means.

For the context, Holo is a wise wolf who is hundreds of years old.

Comment: I think it means "implying continuance from a preceding time" https://www.google.co.in/amp/s/www.collinsdictionary.com/amp/english/yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a slightly literary way to say "would continue to live for hundreds of years" **after** some instant of time implicitly understood. More colloquially, "still" might replace "yet."